# Array Type in Loopback custom remote methode

Tags: javascript, arrays, loopbackjs

I have defined a custom remote method in loopback trying to post some data.

Here is the code of the methode definition:

```
  Workout.prototype.greet = function(userId, exercises, cb) {

   cb(null, userId + ' ' + this.id);
 }

 Workout.remoteMethod('prototype.greet', {
       accepts: [{arg: 'userId', type: 'string', required: true, description:"MyUserId for who created the challenge", http: { source: 'query' }},
                {arg: 'exercises', type: 'array', required: true, description:"Array of exercises which should be added", http: { source: 'body' }}],
       returns: {arg: 'greeting', type: 'object'},
 });
```

When posting data with an empty array in exercises everything works fine see:[Working without data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JG58V.png). But when I insert any information into the array I get an error see: [Not Working with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1P7v4.png)

Hope somebody can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see that error because you send malformed JSON. You omit quotation marks around id. It should look like this:

```
["id": "1"]
```